# Instructive message when a module is disabled accidentally

Tags: debugging

Site breaks without a warning when code of a non-enabled module is called.
(In my project I disabled accidentally a module, while the code is executed by another module.)

The correct way is to add dependencies, but sometimes that is forgotten (and rather old-fashioned). PHP Storm does not check whether a module is active or not; it just validates the call.

Is there a way to get a message when code of a non-enabled module is called?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. In the module that calls the function, use one of the following

Drupal 7:

```
if (module_exists('foo')) { 
  // Use a function provided by the module
}
else {
  drupal_set_message('Something is wrong');
}
```

Drupal 8:

```
$moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
if ($moduleHandler->moduleExists('foo')){
  // Use function provided by the module
}
else {
  drupal_set_message('Something is wrong');
}
```

If your code runs in a context that can use DI, inject the module handler service rather than getting it from `\Drupal`.

You're right, though, dependencies should be used and then this extra wrapping code isn't necessary.

Dependency management is definitely not "old fashioned", by any stretch of the imagination; not in Drupal, and not in the greater world of programming/frameworks. It's a thriving, constantly-improving area of work.

I'm not sure where you got that idea from, but if that's what's stopping you using the proper methods to solve your problem, you should probably think about reevaluating your opinion, as (and no offence meant by this), it's quite frankly just wrong at the moment.

Comment: My problem is, apart from the fact whether dependancies are modern or not, the site just breaks when calling code that is present in the configuration, but not not activated, Php mentions about every error, also the smallest, but when the module is nog activated: the site just breaks without any message!!!

Comment: Well not "no message", your server logs will contain those messages. This just comes down to being a PHP question really; Drupal gives you some things to help, e.g. the examples above, but at the end of the day you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist. It's the calling code's responsibility to make sure the code it calls is available when it gets called